# Sorting coordinate points into paths

Tags: image, algorithm, path, iteration, coordinates

I am given a set of coordinates. The order of the coordinates are somewhat random, but the coordinates are clustered togheter to form different zones. I am struggling to create an algorithm to create individual paths with the coordinates in the proper order. I have been looking through pathfinding and image processing solutions to solve this, but no luck so far.

The coordinates can be as illustrated below.

[image]

Can anyone provide some help with creating an algorithm to sort these coordinates (in the proper order) into paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems a bit challenging, as one of the paths is actually composed of two loops. In this image it is still doable if the correct starting position is chosen, but consider this:

```
   XXX     XX   XXX   XXXXX
  X   X   X  XXX   X X     X
  X   X   X  X  X  XXXXX   X
   XXX     XX    XX  X  XXXX
     XXXXXXX          XX
```

It is easy to see that with arbitrary paths we will end up with the *Seven Bridges of Königsberg". (BTW, that problem is nowadays possible to solve due to some changes in the number of bridges...)

There are at least two possibilities how to change the problem to make it solvable:

1. Allow traversing the same path more than once.
2. Take only loops in considerations.
3. Feed it only with paths that can be drawn without traversing any point more than once.

Finding the path segments is not very challenging, but then combining them into loops requires defining the problem in more detail.

---

In path-finding we need to be able to determine all directions where the path will go from a single point belonging to the path. This can be done by considering all possible 3x3 neighbourhoods for a pixel.

There is an additional requirement: if a path goes from pixel A to a neighbouring pixel B, there must exist a reverse path between these two. This requirement narrows down the possibilities. Also, there is a lot of symmetry (90° rotation, mirroring).

It should be noted that there may be up to 4 close neighbours (in the following configurations):

```
.X.  X.X
XXX  .X.
.X.  X.X
```

The priority rule introduced in the comments above is a good one. So:

- all direct neighbours represent paths to/from a point
- diagonal neighbours represent paths, if they do not have a direct neighbour next to them

The latter rule can be illustrated by:

```
.XX     .N.
XX.  => N .
..X     ..N
```

where N's represent neighbours.

As a result, every point has a list of 0..4 neighbouring point. The neighbouring points have similar lists, so that the connections are one to one.

---

But now we have the challenging part. How to combine the connectivity information into lists?

The easy cases:

- if there are no neighbours (0), the point forms a path by itself
- if there is one neighbour, they belong to the same path
- if there are two neighbours, all three points belong to the same path

After this we have segments and crossings. With the example at the beginning of this answer we have:

```
   111     33   666   AAAAA
  1   1   3  X5X   6 A     A
  1   1   3  4  7  X8X99   A
   11X     X4    77  B  XAAA
     2222222          BB
```

Here 0..B signify the segments and X's are their 3 or 4-crossings.

There seems to be at least one useful rule that can be used to simplify the result:

- if there is a 3-crossing where two branches belong to the same loop, it can be connected into a loop by starting the path next to the crossing

In our example figure this can be applied to the leftmost loop:

```
   111     33   666   AAAAA
  1   1   3  X5X   6 A     A
  1   1   3  4  7  X8X99   A
   111     X4    77  B  XAAA
     1111111          BB
```

And then for each 3-crossing there are three ways to connect it:

```
        /        /        /     
       /        /        /
               /        /
  -----     ---     --  |
       \                \
        \       \        \
         \       \        \
```

For each 4-crossing there are four different possibilities:

```
     |          |           |           |
                           /             \
 ---------  ---   ---   ---   ---   ---   ---
                             /         \
     |          |           |           |
```

As my diagram has five 3-crossings and one 4-crossing, there are 3^5 x 4 = 972 different ways to connect the segments. This can be done with exhaustive search, but then it has to be decided which solution is best. Probably the number of paths needs to be minimized, but is it then better to maximize the longest path or maximize the shortest path? Or something else?

There is some room for optimization, as several different ways to combine segments may give essentially the same result (loops with all ends at a 3-crossing can run two ways).

---

To summarize:

- find the neighbouring connections

  - all next-door neighbours are neighbours
  - diagonal neighbours are neighbours only if there is no next-door neighbour next to them
- connect the easy cases into segments (0, 1, or 2 neighbours)
- create a list of crossings
- group the segments so that completely separate segment groups (separate paths) are handled separately
- eliminate the trivial 3-crossings (two neighbours belonging to the same segment)
- search through all possibilities for the remaining crossings, choose the results you like best

The case shown in the question does not need the last rule, as there are only two trivial 3-crossings.

Comment: If you find it useful (and working), you might even accept it as the anwser. But if you find there is some flaw in the logic, please tell it so that the answer can be improved!

Comment: Actually 4-crossings never occur for any coordinates. I'll make a webpage with javascript methods to show my current solutions, the link will be posted here later today

Answer (score 1):

One solution:

- Take a random point and remove it from the image
- While the current point has neighbors, move to it (new current point = neighbor and remove it from image)
- You now have a sequence of nodes that form a path.

Repeat this until your image is empty.

You will then have a set of paths.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not ensure that the order of the coordinates in the paths will be correct. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/mha4tb51aguq6kb/coordinates.jpg) How can i be sure that the order of the coordinates here will be (a, b, ..., c, d) and not (a, c, ..., b, d)?

Comment: Just try horizontal/vertical neighbors before diagonal

Comment: Im afraid prioritizing horizontal/vertical neighbors before diagonal will split the coordinates into three paths. (https://www.dropbox.com/s/2izertblaa6hmxd/coordinates2.jpg) Consider what the order will be here: First path (a, d, c, ..., e, f, ..., b). Next path will be (g, ...).
Zone 1 and 2 should be merged into one single path.

Comment: You can merge the paths later